# Help with Bash script

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I'm trying to get this script to basically read input from a file on a command line, match the user id in the file using grep and output these lines with line numbers starting from 1)...n in a new file.

so far my script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
linenum=1
grep $USER $1 |
while [ read LINE ]
do
echo $linenum ")" $LINE >> usrout
$linenum+=1
done
```

when i run it `./username file`
i get

```
line 4: [: read: unary operator expected
```

could anyone explain the problem to me?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the [] around `read line` - they should be used to perform tests (file exists, string is empty etc.).

Answer (score 3):

How about the following?

```
$ grep $USER file | cat -n >usrout
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave off the square brackets.

```
while read line; do
  echo $linenum ")" $LINE
done >> usrout
```

Comment: missing the linenum increment :)

Answer (score 1):

just use awk

```
awk -vu="$USER" '$0~u{print ++d") "$0}' file
```

or

```
grep  $USER file |nl
```

or with the shell, (no need to use grep)

```
i=1
while read -r line
do
 case "$line" in
  *"$USER"*) echo $((i++)) $line >> newfile;;
 esac
done <"file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use **grep** with the *-n* (or *--line-number*) switch?

```
$ grep -n ${USERNAME} ${FILE}
```

The *-n* switch gives the line number that the match was found on in the file. From grep's man page:

```
-n, --line-number
      Prefix  each  line of output with the 1-based line number
      within its input file.
```

So, running this against the /etc/passwd file in linux for user test_user, gives:

```
31:test_user:x:5000:5000:Test User,,,:/home/test_user:/bin/bash
```

This shows that the *test_user* account appears on line 31 of the /etc/passwd file.

Answer (score 0):

Also, instead of `$foo+=1`, you should write `foo=$(($foo+1))`.